(React, Node.js) AxiosError 401 occurred when sending POST request, but it worked on Postman
I wrote some code in React to perform a logout function by sending a POST request, and the below error was displayed in the browser console.

Logout error: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

This is my React code:
axios.post('http://*****azure public domain*****/api/accounts/logout', {}, {
        withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('Logout successful');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Logout failed:', error);
    });

This is the code for CORS and cookies in my server.js.
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        callback(null, true);
    },
    methods: ["POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}));

Lastly this is my logout controller code.
exports.logout = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
        req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error during logout'
                });
            }
            res.clearCookie('session_cookie_name');
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Logged out successfully'
            });
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Already logged out'
        });
    }
};

I think I've set the credentials correctly, but I don't know what the problem is. It worked successfully on Postman.
I tried using the axios.create method, but it returned the same error with no change.
import axios from 'axios';
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://******azure public domain******/api',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
export default apiClient;

export const logout = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = await apiClient.post('/accounts/logout');
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGOUT'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Logout error:', err);
    }
};


Check the request's cookie in postman and axios, are they same? This looks like the cookie issue, maybe not the same domain.

As you said, the domain of the backend (Azure VM public Ipv4 address) and the domain of the frontend (localhost) were different, which blocked the Set-Cookie setting, so I checked in the Network tab by pressing F12. I built the frontend code as a static file and put it on the VM to check, and the problem was solved. Thank you so much.
